# Storing entry input from GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Lets say I have this code

```
import math
from tkinter import *


def close_window():
    root.destroy()

def fileName():
    filename = content.get()
    return filename;



root = Tk()
content = StringVar()

L2 = Label(root, text = "The Program").grid(row = 0, sticky = E)


L1 = Label(root, text = "Enter filename").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky =    E)
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5, textvariable = content).grid(row = 1, column = 1)


B1 = Button(root, text = "Ok", command = fileName).grid(row = 2, column = 0 )
B2 = Button(root, text = "Quit", command = close_window).grid(row = 2, column    = 1)


root.mainloop()

print(fileName())
```

Now the problem is I want to store the content I enter in E1 (so I later can do things to it) but how do I access it "outside" of the GUI?

The program I want to make is that the user enters a file name, then it runs a bunch of functions on the input and then produce a textmessage based on whats given, but I cant access the input since
    fileName()
doesnt return anything.

Comment: You shouldn't be referring to `content` in your `fileName` function. Try passing the content as a parameter to the function and then referring to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this does what you wanted but now it prints on button click and you have you filename variable set to content.get()

```
import math
from tkinter import *


def close_window():
    root.destroy()

def fileName():
    filename = content.get()
    return filename;

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

def prnt():
    print(content.get())

root = Tk()
content = StringVar()

L2 = Label(root, text = "The Program").grid(row = 0, sticky = E)


L1 = Label(root, text = "Enter filename").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky =    E)
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5, textvariable = content).grid(row = 1, column = 1)


B1 = Button(root, text = "Ok", command = combine_funcs(fileName,prnt)).grid(row = 2, column = 0 )
B2 = Button(root, text = "Quit", command = close_window).grid(row = 2, column    = 1)


root.mainloop()


print(fileName())
```